# Refreshing Label content every second WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to refresh a label content every second. So I define two methods as below. I use `startStatusBarTimer()` in my constructor of `Window`.

codes:

```
private void startStatusBarTimer()
{
    System.Timers.Timer statusTime = new System.Timers.Timer();

    statusTime.Interval = 1000;

    statusTime.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(statusTimeElapsed);

    statusTime.Enabled = true;
}

private void statusTimeElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    lblNow.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");      
}
```

But I get this error:

*The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.*

What is wrong? Or What can I do?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/timer-in-wpf/

Comment: A thread can't access a control. Basicly because the "root" thread is already controlling it and 2 threads can't control it together. There's a way to access these controls, just Google 'WPF Thread Control' or 'C# Thread Control'

Comment: I am curious why are you declaring `System.Timers.Timer statusTime` inside the constructor, and not in the class definition!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are facing [thread affinity](http://vkishorekumar.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/what-is-thread-affinity/) issue. Since elapsed event is called on `background thread`, you cannot access UI controls from background thread. You need to put your action on `UI dispatcher` so that it gets dispatch to UI thread -

```
private void statusTimeElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
    {
       lblNow.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");   
    });
}
```

**OR**

You can use `DispatcherTimer` which is built specially for this purpose. You can access UI controls from its `Tick` event handler. Refer to the sample here at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

just use following code for refreshing any control in WPF application.you must past this class in your same namespace.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        private static Action EmptyDelegate = delegate() { };

        public static void Refresh(this UIElement uiElement)
        {
            uiElement.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, EmptyDelegate);
        }
    }
```

after that use like following.

```
lable1.Refresh();
```

Comment: For some reason this only works for me when I use the release build. When I'm in debug mode the uielements don't update.